# How to retrieve data from array using split function in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a list with some service names along with two textboxes. The first textbox is where you enter the words that you will want the service to include and the other textbox is where you would enter the words to exclude. Therefore if I enter tbOne = SQL and for tbTWo = Browser,Server. I should only get SQL Administration. Instead it loops through every item in the list and displays it. How can I prevent this. Please help.

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string tbOne = TextBox1.Text;
    string[] tbOneArray = tbOne.Split(',');

    string tbTwo = TextBox2.Text;
    string[] tbTwoArray = tbTwo.Split(',');


    var service1 = "SQL Server Agent";
    var service2 = "SQL Browser";
    var service3 = "SQL Administration";

    List<string> listOfServices = new List<string>();

    listOfServices.Add(service1);
    listOfServices.Add(service2);
    listOfServices.Add(service3);

    foreach (var service in listOfServices)
    {
        foreach (var includedItem in tbOneArray)
        {
            foreach (var excludedItem in tbTwoArray)
            {
                if (service.Contains(includedItem) && !service.Contains(excludedItem))
                {
                    Response.Write(service);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: 1. Iteration: "SQL Browser" includes "SQL" and "Browser" -> no Write, 2. Iteration: "SQL Browser" includes "SQL" and not "Server" => Write ... See the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach (var service in listOfServices.Where(x=> tbOneArray.Any(a=> x.Contains(a)) &&
!tbTwoArray.Any(a=> x.Contains(a))))
{
  Response.Write(service);
}
```

Comment: To convert from array to a list (ToList) :)

Comment: Yes, I know, but there is no reason to do so. `Any` works on the array as well. It is an extension method and works on any type implementing `IEnumerable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the LINQ `Contains` extension method with the `StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` to make the search case insensitive.

```
var filteredServices = listOfServices
    .Where(svc =>
        svc.Split().Any(w => tbOneArray.Contains(w, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) &&
        !svc.Split().Any(w => tbTwoArray.Contains(w, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)));
foreach (string service in filteredServices) {
    Response.Write(service);
}
```

To search only for whole words, I split the service name into single words.

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
if (service.Contains(includedItem) && !(service.Contains(excludedItem)))
  {
           Response.Write(service);
  }
```

Comment: Aside from the extra unnecessary parenthesis, I'm struggling to see a difference between this and OP's code.